# How to read unicode characters accurately

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unicode

I have a text file containing what I am told are unicode characters, for example:

`\320\222\320\21015-25'ish per main or \320\222\320\21020-40'ish per starter`

Which should read:

`£15-25'ish per main or £20-40'ish per main starter`

However, when viewing this text in Firefox, the output is mangled with various unwanted characters.

So, are these really unicode characters? And if so, how can I convert them to a form which is displayable correctly?

Comment: Definitely read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html.

Answer (score 3):

You need to:

- know the encoding of the text file
- read the data without losing information (either by reading it as binary or by reading it as text with the right encoding)
- write the data with the right encoding (either by writing it out in binary and specifying the original encoding, or writing it out as text in an encoding which you *also* specify in the headers)

Try to separate out the problem into "reading" and/or "writing". Do you know the encoding of the file? What do you have to do with the file? When you've written it with backslashes, is that *actually* what's in the file (i.e. an escaped form) or is it actually just a "normal" text encoding such as UTF-8?